# AngularJS Unit testing a directive that needs the $compile provider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm trying to test a directive. 
This directive use the $compile provider.

I would try to expect if $compile will been called but providing it in the test I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$compile(angular.element(html))(scope)')
```

I know why is that happening (I'm *overriding* with a fake mock the actual $compile provider) but I don't really know how can I fix that problem.

This is the actual test code:

```
describe('directive', function () {
  var scope, mockCompile;
  beforeEach(function () {
    mockCompile = jasmine.createSpy();

    module('directive', function ($provide) {
      $provide.value('$compile', mockCompile);
    });

    var html = '<div directive="foo"></div>';

    // The problem is there. I'm injecting the mocked compile service
    // Not the real one
    inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile(angular.element(html))(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it("should test the directive", function () {
    //Act.
    scope.$apply();

    //Assert.
    expect(mockCompile).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have included [angular-mocks.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-mocks.js) for testing.

Then, each service you mock needs to begin **and end** with an underscore;

`inject(function ($compile, $rootScope)`

Should really by;

`inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_)`